# なぜメモリのコピーは遅いのですか？

Tags: c++

コピー元が不必要な場面では速度のためにコピーからムーブに変えたほうが良いとのことで、そのように実装し変えたところ、確かに早くなりました。では、なぜそもそもコピーはコンピュータにとって重いのでしょうか。
ライトバック方式のときでも、書き込みはコストになりますか？それとも単にたくさんの命令を実行するからでしょうか？

例：

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <array>
#define SIZE 10000000

struct A{
    std::shared_ptr<std::array<int, SIZE>> data;
    A(){
        data = std::make_shared<std::array<int, SIZE>>();
    }
    A(const A& other){
        std::cout << "copy" << std::endl;
        data = std::make_shared<std::array<int, SIZE>>();
        *data = *(other.data);
    }
    A(A&& other){
        std::cout << "move" << std::endl;
        data = other.data;
    }
};

int main(){
    A a;
    auto b = a; // 遅い
    auto c = std::move(a); // 早い
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: 実際にコピーの場合とムーブの場合の両方のソースコードを示したほうが良さそうな質問だと思います。memcpy()とmemove()の話なのかなとも思いましたがそれならばmemmove()のほうが速いとかはなさそうな気がします。

Comment: @hidezzz フィードバックありがとうございます。質問の内容を修正致しました。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

質問文のコードは比較になっていません。

> ```
> data = std::make_shared<std::array<int, SIZE>>();
> ```

このコードはメモリ確保が走ります。対して、ムーブの場合、メモリ確保が生じません。

Comment: あ、確かにそうでした。